# Struggling to find the total number of rows that meet a certain variable grouped by another variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm performing some light analysis on an NFL kickers' dataset, and am trying to find the total number of kicks made from 18-29yds grouped by each kicker. The dataset's rows contain every made or missed field goal for each kicker, along with the distance and some other variables irrelevant to this issue. I'm using groupby() and then the sum function within the summarise function, but it is returning 1 for every kicker. I have tried different combinations, trying to use filter() as well, but the results keep returning 1 for each kicker. Pics of my code are attached. Any help is appreciated :)

Some code I have tried:

```
kicks20to29 <- nfl_kicks1%>%
  group_by(Kicker)%>%
  count(filter(nfl_kicks1$`FG Length`>=18 & nfl_kicks1$`FG Length`<=29))
```

```
kicks20to29 <- nfl_kicks1%>%
  group_by(Kicker)%>%
  filter(`FG Length`>=18 & `FG Length`<=29)
```

`dput` output:

```
structure(list(Quarter = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4), `Possession Team` = c("NE", 
"NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE"), `Wind Speed` = c("6", "6", "12", 
"12", "12", "12"), Down = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Distance = c(13, 
7, 2, 6, 9, 12), YardLine = c(22, 20, 2, 6, 35, 25), `FG Length` = c(39, 
37, 19, 23, 52, 42), `4Q to tie or take lead` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), Result = c("Miss", "Miss", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Miss"
), `Success Rate` = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), Kicker = c("A.Vinatieri", 
"A.Vinatieri", "A.Vinatieri", "A.Vinatieri", "A.Vinatieri", "A.Vinatieri"
), `# career kicks in study` = c(766, 766, 766, 766, 766, 766
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Just edited the post. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use the `tally` function, which counts the number of rows per group.

```
library(tidyverse)
nfl_kicks1 %>%
  group_by(Kicker) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(`FG Length` >= 18 & `FG Length` <= 29) %>%
  tally(name = "Number of Kicks")
## A tibble: 1 x 2
#  Kicker      `Number of Kicks`
#  <chr>                   <int>
#1 A.Vinatieri                 2
```

Comment: I did have one more question. Doesn't this calculate the number of kicks they've attempted from 18-29 yards? I would need to add ``` 'Success Rate == 1' ``` to the filter condition to count the makes, right?

Comment: You could ```group_by(Kicker, `Success Rate`)``` to get a row for successes and failures. Or you could add ```& `Success Rate` == 1``` to only get counts for successes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by` + `summarise` :

```
library(dplyr)

nfl_kicks1 %>%
  group_by(Kicker) %>%
  summarise(n_kicks = sum(`FG Length` >= 18 & `FG Length` <= 29))
```